# How to use the POST method in web.py to update a table in a postgreSQL database?

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, web.py

Here's my web.py code so far. I want to use my web server to update a table.

```
import web


urls = ('/', 'Index')

render = web.template.render('templates/')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

web.config.debug = True

db = web.database(dbn='postgres', db='my_db', user='postgres', pw='******', host='localhost')

class Index:

    def GET(self):
        drivers = db.select("drivers")
        return render.index(drivers)

    def POST(self, name):
        return "post"

if __name__ == '__main__':app.run()
```

Right now it takes what's in the table and prints it out in the browser. But I want to implement some logic that adds numeric values to the table as a while loop runs using the post method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the Postgres insertion as follows,

```
def POST(self):
    sequence_id = db.insert('test1', col1=5, col2=3)  # insert(tablename, seqname=None, _test=False, **values)
```

Refer [this](http://lost-theory.org/webpydocs/module-web.db.html) for more details.

You may use,

```
data = json.loads(web.data()) # convert to dictionary if needed using json.loads
```

or

```
data = web.input().number # number is the key which holds the data
```

depending on how you send data to POST method.

eg: If `content-type = application/json` use `web.input().number`

Refer [this](http://webpy.org/cookbook/) as well.